# How long should it take to return a 200mb blob from SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sharepoint, blob

I have SQL 2008 R2 supporting a SharePoint 2010 environment. Some of the files will be stupidly large (i.e. 200mb). While Remote Blob Storage will be added to our platform in the future, I want to understand what reasonable performance might look like in getting a 200mb file to the user.

The network between the SharePoint WFE is only one part. Simply reading the blob from disk and passing it through the SharePoint layer MUST take some time, but I have no idea how to calculate this (or what additional information people need to help out)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you considering storing the blobs on a shared drive and just passing file paths between the applications?

Comment: Changing the infrastructure is not possible atm. This includes altering the SQL configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a very complex question and requires knowledge of the environment in which you are working. The network as you rightly say is one aspect but there are many others. Traffic congestion, QoS, SQL Server versions, setup, hardware, etc Then there are issues with how the Web Front Ends are handing off the data and the HTTP pipe to the user, the browser in use, etc, etc.

Have a look at installing the Developer Dashboard for SharePoint 2010 and you'll be able to see all of the steps in fecthing and delivering files and how long each one will take you. You'll be quite surprised at how detailed the path is.

[SharePoint 2010 Developer Dashboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512745.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for this Paul, although the DD wont give me data for a specific file download (i.e. for a PDF). I'll share some numbers with you: sub ms lan between WFE&SQL with high-speed SAN via Fibre connections. I know that I have 14mbits available at the network level (ignore contention) which caps performance at around 2:26secs. We're not going to get better than that. However, I would think maybe a 10 second delay to deserialise the blob and present it for downloading is reasonable, though possibly optimistic. 200 seconds would be excessive. I'm really looking for a gut-feel.

Comment: I did a trial on our system (45Mbit pipe to the DC). Upload of a 160MB zip was 49.7 second and download was 24.3 seconds. Personally I think this is respectable performance. Your mileage and results will vary of course but theres a benchmark to start with at least. (SP2010 2 WFEs, 2 APP, Mirrored SQL 2008 R2)

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the large size, you should consider activating the BlobCache feature if your large content is currently stored in a document library.

That will put it on your WFEs after first access, deliver it with proper expiration headers and completely cut the load from the SQL Server. Imagine 20 concurrent users accessing a 200mb file. If not in a blobcache, your farm will have a hard time swallowing that useless load.

The first access will be longer than your test scenario when you request it with as single user but any further access will be a fast as IIS 7 is able to deliver it and the network capacities up to your clients.

Hope it helped.